# Como alterar o ícone de localização do GPS no Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Eu queria saber como alterar aquele ícone vermelho que marca a localização do GPS para colocar uma foto localizada no drawable. Apenas queria saber qual código eu deveria adicionar para ter o resultado sugerido.

O código é o seguinte:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    //11.456, -78910
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-7.937696, -34.897499);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("******"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá você pode usar a class Marker

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

```
GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.

Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.sua_img)));
```

Comment: por algum motivo o aplicativo não abre no celular porem irei ver o problema no logcat, muito obrigado.

Comment: Adiciona o log que fica mais fácil de te ajudarmos.